# Data Migration from MOSS 2007 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have done a migration project for one of our client.
This migration was done from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010.
After the migration was completed we developed lot of new webparts, lists ,application pages in this newly migrated farm in SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010.

However the entire project took around 1 year due to some unavoidable delays. During this one year our client was using MOSS 2007 sites for there work. hence the data in MOSS 2007 farm/sites was continuously updated.

Our client needs to go live in next month and also needs the sites/lists/libraries which are migrated in new SP 2010 farm to be updated as per the MOSS 2007 farm.

Kindly suggest best possible way to achieve this data migration since last 1 year from MOSS 2007 to newly migrated SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010 farm.

Kindly note we have done lot of customization and new developments in newly created SP 2010 farm.

Thanks and regards,
Amien

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go the cheap route, like I did...

-*Export Lists as a Spreadsheet* -> Import External Spreadsheet into said webpart.  I believe Bulk Import is still available in 2010's dataview unlike 2013 (my migration).

**Lesson Learn**:  Not all columns translated over to next version.  Some (Choice) had to be set back to choice, but it retained the selections.  Others (Text w/Append text turned on) did not bring anything over.  People Selector columns had to be recreated.  Attachments had to be manually exported.  Lists that pulled information from other lists had to be remapped.

-*Utilize Explorer View in order to bulk move (Drag and drop) Libraries between Sites*.  There are powershell scripts to do this, but did not have the time to test.

**Lesson Learned**:  Fairly seamless process, can be time consuming depending on amount of content in library.

I would fight hard to have them purchase software.  We did a lot of customization and it was painful.

Answer (score 0):

Two Possible ways I am thinking.

1. Use the 3rd party tools to just migrate the data with metadata...their are many tools out in market i.e. [ShareGate](http://en.share-gate.com/), [Metlogix](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx), [DocAve](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/) etc
2. you can migrate from MOSS 2007 to 2010( complete migration, then apply the customization. do this over the weekend to less down time and also mark the 2007 farm as readonly so that no new content added to 2007 farms.